# Javascript and CSS Terminal website, error display input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a terminal website like the following github :
https://github.com/heberleonard2/terminal-style-portfolio-page

I have 2 issue that I would like to tackle:

--> I want to create a Contact section where it would take to the user input and then send it by email using django framework

--> It must match the same style as the p and section class tags

@javascript

```
const app = document.querySelector("#app");

// delay the execution of code
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
    
// Event listener for "Enter" key press
app.addEventListener("keypress", async function(event){
  if(event.key === "Enter"){
    await delay(150);
    // get user input value
    getInputValue();
    // remove the input field
    removeInput();
    // delay before creating a new line
    await delay(150);
    // create a new line
    new_line();
  }
});

// Event listener for click on the terminal window
app.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // set focus on input field
  const input = document.querySelector("input");
  input.focus();
});

// initialize the terminal
async function open_terminal(){
  createText("Welcome");
  await delay(700);
  createText("Starting the server...");
  await delay(1500);
  createText("You can run several commands:");
 
  createCode("about me", "Who am i and what do i do.");
  createCode("all", "See all commands.");
  createCode("social -a", "All my social networks.");
  createCode("skills", "check out my skills");
  createCode("contact", "Contact me");

  await delay(500);
  new_line();
}

// create a new prompt and input field for the user to enter input
function new_line(){
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  const span1 = document.createElement("span");
  const span2 = document.createElement("span");
  p.setAttribute("class", "path")
  p.textContent = "# user";
  span1.textContent = " in";
  span2.textContent = " ~/Henry Dumont";
  p.appendChild(span1);
  p.appendChild(span2);
  app.appendChild(p);
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "type")
  const i = document.createElement("i");
  i.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-angle-right icone")
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  div.appendChild(i);
  div.appendChild(input);
  app.appendChild(div);
  input.focus();
}

// remove the current input field
function removeInput(){
  const div = document.querySelector(".type");
  app.removeChild(div);
}

// handle user input
async function getInputValue(){
  const value = document.querySelector("input").value;
  if(value === "all"){
    // display true value
    trueValue(value);
    // display command examples
    createCode("projects", "My github page with my projects. Follow me there ;)");
    createCode("about me", "My IT carreer as a Data Analyst adn web developer");
    createCode("social -a", "All my social networks.");
    createCode("skills", "check out my skills");
    createCode("contact", "Contact me");
    createCode("clear", "Clean the terminal.");
  }
  else if(value === "projects"){
    trueValue(value);
    // display github page
    createText("<a href='https://github.com/xxx' target='_blank'><i class='fab fa-github white'></i> github.com/heberleonard2</a>");
  }
  else if(value === "about me"){
    trueValue(value);
    // display bio
    createText("Hi, I am xxx, a Data/Dev ;)");
    createText("I love to do small IT project. I love to explore new technologies and learning them. I mainly use the snake language ;)");
  }
  else if(value === "social -a"){
    trueValue(value);
    // display social network links
    createText("<a href='https://github.com/' target='_blank'><i class='fab fa-github white'></i> github.com/</a>");
    createText("<a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/xx/' target='_blank'><i class='fab fa-linkedin-in white'></i> linkedin.com/in/xxx/</a>")
  }

  else if(value === "skills"){
    trueValue(value);
    // display  skill description
    createText(" Database : SQL Server - MySQL - MongoDB  <br> Programming Language: Python - JavaScript - SQL - Django Framework - C# <br>  Software : Power BI - Power Automate - SSIS -  Azure DevOps <br> WEB : HTML - CSS <br> Operating system : Windows 10 - Linux - Unbuntu - Kali linux ");
  }
  
  else if(value === "social"){
    trueValue(value);
    // display  error message if write wrong value
    createText("Didn't you mean: social -a?")
  }
 
  else if(value === "contact"){
    trueValue(value);
    // create input fields for message and email
    createInput("Please write your message:", "message-field");
    createInput("Please write your email:", "email-field");

    // select input fields
    const messageInput = document.querySelector("#message-field");
    const emailInput = document.querySelector("#email-field");

    // store  message values on enter key press
    messageInput.addEventListener("keydown", async function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        const messageValue = messageInput.value;
        if (messageValue) {
          // remove the input field
          removeInput(messageInput);
          // delay before creating a new line
          await delay(150);
          // create a new line
          new_line();
          // set focus on email field
          emailInput.focus();
        } else {
          console.error("Message field cannot be empty.");
        }
      }
    });

    // store email values on enter key press
    emailInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        const emailValue = emailInput.value;
        if (emailValue) {
          // call Django views to store values
          saveValues(messageValue, emailValue);
        } else {
          console.error("Email field cannot be empty.");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  else if(value === "clear"){
    // Remove every command text when write clear
    document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
    document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
  }
  else{
    // write wrong command + display command error name 
    falseValue(value);
    createText(`command not found: ${value}`)
  }
}

function trueValue(value){
  
  const div = document.createElement("section");
  div.setAttribute("class", "type2")
  const i = document.createElement("i");
  i.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-angle-right icone")
  const mensagem = document.createElement("h2");
  mensagem.setAttribute("class", "sucess")
  mensagem.textContent = `${value}`;
  div.appendChild(i);
  div.appendChild(mensagem);
  app.appendChild(div);
}

function falseValue(value){
  
  const div = document.createElement("section");
  div.setAttribute("class", "type2")
  const i = document.createElement("i");
  i.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-angle-right icone error")
  const mensagem = document.createElement("h2");
  mensagem.setAttribute("class", "error")
  mensagem.textContent = `${value}`;
  div.appendChild(i);
  div.appendChild(mensagem);
  app.appendChild(div);
}

function createText(text, classname){
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  
  p.innerHTML =
  text
  ;
  app.appendChild(p);
}

function createCode(code, text){
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.setAttribute("class", "code");
  p.innerHTML =
 `${code} <br/><span class='text'> ${text} </span>`;
  app.appendChild(p);
}

// function  to send values to django's view 
function saveValues(messageValue, emailValue) {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      // display success message to user
      createCode("Success", "Your message and email have been saved!");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/", true);  // Changed the URL to match Django's URL
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  const data = `message=${encodeURIComponent(messageValue)}&email=${encodeURIComponent(emailValue)}`;
  xhttp.send(data);
}




open_terminal();


/*
open_terminal(): This asynchronous function initializes the terminal interface by creating several lines of text and command examples.

new_line(): This function adds a new line to the terminal interface, simulating a new command prompt.

removeInput(): This function removes the current input field from the terminal interface.

getInputValue(): This asynchronous function captures the user's input, checks it against a list of valid commands, and responds accordingly.

trueValue(), falseValue(): These functions are used to display the user's input in the terminal interface, with trueValue() used for valid commands and falseValue() used for invalid commands.

createText(), createCode(): These functions add a line of plain text or a code example to the terminal interface, respectively.*/
```

@CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track
  {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      
      background-color: #555;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar
  {
      width: 12px;
      background-color: #555;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
  {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      background-color: rgb(129, 129, 129);
  }
  .white{
    color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
  }
  .blue{
    color:#9CEAF3;
  }
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  }
  body{
    background-color:#393A59;
  
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:100%;
    max-width:800px;
    height:500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin:20px;
    cursor: text;
  }
  .menu{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
  
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #424040;
    padding: 0 8px;
    cursor:default;
  }
  .menu .button{
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-right:8px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .red{background-color:#F5544D;}
  .yellow{background-color:#FABD2F;}
  .green{background-color:#47D043;}
  div.title{
    flex:1;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .menu h1{
    font-size:13px;
    color:#9c9c9c;
  
  }
  .buttons-flex{
    position: absolute;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  @media (max-width:500px){
    .buttons-flex{
      position: unset;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width:330px){
    .menu h1{
      display:none;
    }
  }
  #app{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:#282A35;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:8px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p{
    font-size:16px;
    color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
    padding:8px 0;
  }
  h2{
    font-size:16px;
    color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
  }
  p.code{
    color:#66C2CD;
    margin-left:8px;
  }
  span.text{
    margin-left:16px;
    color:white;
  }
  p.path{
    color:#F7FCA0;
  }
  p.path span{
    color:#6A77D2;
  }
  p.path span + span{
    color:#9CEAF3;
  }
  
  .sucess{
    color:#5AD786;
  }
  .error{
    color:#F78F85;
  }
  p.response{
    color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
  }
  
  input{
    border:none;
    background-color: unset;
    color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
    width:100%;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  }
  input:focus{
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: unset;
    
  }
  .type{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding:8px 0;
  }
  .type2{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding:8px 0;
  }
  .icone{
    color:#5AD786;
    padding-right:8px;
  }
  
  .icone.error{
    color:#F78F85;
  }

  /* 
  Modification made by henry on 20/05/23
  */
  input{
    font-size:16px;
    color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
    padding:8px 0;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #282A35;
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  }
  
  input:focus{
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #282A35;
  }
```

How could it be fixed in the html and css for the contact section?
How to avoid it considers as wrong command when after writing the contact input ?